# Adding headers to an api in AWS api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am a very new developer, so I am very sorry if this is a basic question. I have an api created on an instance in AWS. This works fine with direct calls to that instance. However, a load balancer was recently created to address scale concerns. This has been causing CORS issues which I have been trying to fix. The only thing I could find was to use AWS api gateway to create another api and add the Access-Control-Allow-etc. headers manually to it as ELBs do not support CORS. Any suggestions about better solutions would be greatly appreciated. If not, I have a few questions about this new api.

1. How do I add authentication tokens to this new api?
2. How do I find the ip address of this new api?
   I am very new to tech in general. Sorry if these are very basic questions. Thank you for all your help.